# iOS UITableView Custom RowHeightt

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, tableview, containers

I am using Swift 2 on Xcode 7
I have a ViewController with a containerView. The containerView calls a  childViewController which has a tableView. In the tableView I have put a custom tableViewCell with a row height of 60 pts.

Issue: in the run mode: when the tableView is shown as part of parentcontroller in the container -- the row height does not remain 60 pts. It becomes some arbitrary height. This new arbitrary height has nothing to do with size of container. Even if I make the container - smaller/ bigger- the new height remains. I want to it to be my custom height which I have designated in the childViewController

Below is my code to add the childViewController and setting the autolayout

```
 func addController(controller: UIViewController)
{
    addChildViewController(controller)
    containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
    controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    //Layouting within view controller
    var constraints = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[view]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view" : controller.view])
    constraints += NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[view]|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view" : controller.view])
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints(constraints)
    didMoveToParentViewController(controller)
    currentController = controller
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) Are you using a custom cell .xib? If you are, make sure it's height property is set in the .xib file

2.) In your storyboard file, check that when you click on the Prototype cell, of the TableView, your height is set:

[image]

3.) In your tableviewcontroller, did you specify the height?:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 72
    }
```

Replace the 72 across the board with what you want, and it should update unless you have something else going on! :)

Comment: Adding the function worked. I had put the row height in the attributes inspector but that was not enough for some reason. Any case.. Thanks:)